# PHP $_POST, which part of the form does it connect to?

Tags: php, html

This ia a beginner's question. If part of my form looks like this

```
<p>Subject name: <input type="text" name="menu" value="" 
                    id="menu_name" /></p>
```

and I want to use $_POST to get the data that is submitted, is $_POST reading the form "name" or "value" or "id."

For example, using the form above, would it be

```
$_POST['menu'];
```

or

```
$_POST['menu_name'];
```

or something else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses the `name` attribute, and the value comes from the `value` attribute.

So you would access `$_POST['menu']`.

You can easily examine what's in a post with `var_dump($_POST)`.

You could also view it directly with `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` which is handy in some situations, or through the PHP protocol like so...

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Although this doesn't work with a `form` that has the `enctype="multitpart/form-data"` attribute.

The `id` attribute is never sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The key for the associative array is the `name` attribute of the form element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['menu'];
```

would be the correect way.  forms are connected to the `name`

Answer (score 1):

It is connected to the `name`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

You can see the whole array of `$_POST` by doing

```
var_dump $_POST;
```